# Writing a function that uses a given recursive formula to return the nth number in the sequence

Tags: python, recursion

Given =1.5(−1)−0.5(−2) for=2,3,…. (0)=(0) (1)=(1)

I need to write a function that uses the given formula to return the nth number in the sequence. I was given the following starter code:

```
# function to produce n-th number of the following sequence:
# f0=s0, f1=s1 (s0, s1 -- preset parameters)
# f_n =1.5* f_{n-1} -0.5*f_{n-2} 
# Input: n, s0, s1
# Return: f_n
def get_n_value( n, s0, s1 ):

    # handle special cases for the first three elements
    if n<0:
        return 0

    elif n==0:
        return s0
    
    elif n==1:
        return s1
    

    # the general case, n>1
    else:

        # ADD YOUR CODE HERE
        # STORE THE FINAL RESULT IN fn VARIABLE

        return fn
```

I tried to use a list to store the elements of each iteration of a loop, and then add the desired elements together.

Comment: Use a dictionary to hold previously calculated values. This is called "memoizing". You can also use `functools.cache` to automate this.

Comment: It looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you. Please give it a try first, and then ask a specific question about a detail if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store anything, just call the function recursively twice.

```
def get_n_value( n, s0, s1 ):
    # handle special cases for the first three elements
    if n<0:
        return 0
    elif n==0:
        return s0
    elif n==1:
        return s1

    # the general case, n>1
    else:
        return 1.5 * get_n_value(n-1, s0, s1) - 0.5 * get_n_value(n-2, s0, s1)
```

This will do lots of redundant calculations of the same values, you can use the `@functools.cache` decorator to optimize that.